# Copy/publish images linked from the html files to another server and update the HTML files referencing them

Tags: bash, ftp, sed, grep

I am publishing content from a Drupal CMS to static HTML pages on another domain, hosted on a second server. Building the HTML files was simple (using PHP/MySQL to write the files).

I have a list of images referenced in my HTML, all of which exist below the /userfiles/ directory.

```
cat *.html | grep -oE [^\'\"]+userfiles[\/.*]*/[^\'\"] | sort | uniq
```

Which produces a list of files

```
http://my.server.com/userfiles/Another%20User1.jpg
http://my.server.com/userfiles/image/image%201.jpg
...
```

My next step is to copy these images across to the second server and translate the  tags in the html files.

---

I understand that **sed** is probably the tool I would need. E.g.:

```
sed 's/[^"]\+userfiles[\/image]\?\/\([^"]\+\)/\/images\/\1/g'
```

Should change *http://my.server.com/userfiles/Another%20User1.jpg* to */images/Another%20User1.jpg*, but I cannot work out exactly how I would use the script. I.e. can I use it to update the files in place or do I need to juggle temporary files, etc. Then how can I ensure that the files are moved to the correct location on the second server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use sed to change the file in-place using the -i option.

For your use it's up to you if it's easier/better to create a new file with the changes from the old, then copy to the 2nd domain using scp (or something similar).  Or it may be easier to copy the file first, then modify it once it's on the remote server (less management of new filenames this way).

Comment: The html files are generated solely for this purpose, so modifying them in-place is my preferred option.

Comment: cat *.html | grep -oE [^\"]+userfiles[\/.*]*/[^\"]+ |sort|uniq | sed 's/
\(.*\/\(.*\)\)/cp \"\/var\/www\/drupal\1\" \".\/\2\"/g' | sed 's/%20/ /g' >> mov
e_images.sh
    
    bash move_images.sh

    sed -i 's/\/userfiles\/\([^\"\/]*\)/\1/g' *.html